# Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime HttpClient async with the same result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

I'm working with Windows Phone Runtime API.
I declare a timer, which every 2 seconds does async http connection in `Listen` method.

```
Timer t = new Timer(Listen, null, 0, 2000);
```

`Listen` method:

```
private async void Listen(object state)
{
    string url = "http://www.mywebpage.com?data=my_data";
    string responseBodyAsText = null;
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
        responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        //...
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(responseBodyAsText);
    httpClient.Dispose();
}
```

My problem is that `responseBodyAsText` contains always the same data (given the same uri) and not as I would expect different data according to my external actions (modifying web page or different results with the same uri).
Does `HttpClient` remembers content during liftime of application? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpClient` does have caching on by default. You can turn it off by passing it an `HttpBaseProtocolFilter`:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter
{
    CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent,
    CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;
}
```

Side note: You could also, instead of a `Timer`, use `Task.Delay` to achieve the timer behavior (it internally uses one):

```
private async Task ListenAsync()
{
    while (someCondition)
    {
        string url = "http://www.mywebpage.com?data=my_data";
        string responseBodyAsText = null;
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
                responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             }
            catch
            {
                //...
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(responseBodyAsText);
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `responseBodyAsText` and `response` (with an instantiation of `HttpResponseMessage`, in this case) instead of just declaring it?

Comment: +1 for great answer, I never knew you could disable caching this way. I am just used to always having to put a random number at the end of my urls.

Comment: @Paulo I'm not to sure what the OP is doing with those members, they seem like class level ones. I just dodn't change his example. He should clarify.

Comment: @PauloMorgado No reason either. It was fast made piece of code which I will refactor later.